# sqllite update statement not working

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have problem with Sqllite update statement, its not working. I do not know why because everything seems ok. Error code is 0

```
char *q; // query
char fp[MAX_PATH];
q="UPDATE search SET ustat=1 WHERE fpath=?";
for(int i=0; i<=6; i++){
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, q, strlen(q), &pointer, 0) == SQLITE_OK){
        //cout<<"\n\n inside loop i values is "<<i<<"\n\n";
        snprintf(fp,MAX_PATH,xbx[i].fpaths,0);
        sqlite3_bind_text(pointer, 1,  fp, strlen(fp), 0); // file name
        sqlite3_step(pointer);   // prepare statemnt Ready
        sqlite3_finalize(pointer);   
    }
}
```

I was using structure in bind text statement then I thought maybe the problem is due to structure then I change it to local buffer but no success.

update:  i try to remove the loop and set things manually but its still not working anything wrong with update statement ?????? error code 0

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, q, strlen(q), &pointer, 0) == SQLITE_OK){
                        sqlite3_bind_text(pointer, 1,  xbx[0].fpaths, sizeof(xbx[0].fpaths), 0); // file name
                        sqlite3_bind_text(pointer, 1,  xbx[1].fpaths, sizeof(xbx[1].fpaths), 0);
                        sqlite3_bind_text(pointer, 1,  xbx[2].fpaths, sizeof(xbx[2].fpaths), 0);
                        sqlite3_bind_text(pointer, 1,  xbx[3].fpaths, sizeof(xbx[3].fpaths), 0);
                        sqlite3_bind_text(pointer, 1,  xbx[4].fpaths, sizeof(xbx[4].fpaths), 0);
                        sqlite3_step(pointer);   // prepare statemnt Ready   
                        sqlite3_finalize(pointer);  // delete  prepared statement
            }
```

Comment: Move `sqlite_prepare_v2()` outside the loop.

Comment: by moving sqlite_prepare_v2() outside of loop .... it crash it i value =3   .... also ustat is not updated to 1

Comment: When you move the `sqlite3_prepare` out of the loop, the `sqlite3_finalize` must be moved too, and you need to call `sqlite3_reset` after each iteration. Also, check the return code of `sqlite3_step`!

Comment: not working i try every possible way ... please someone try it if someone get success then share it because i search on google everyone have problem with sqllite in loop

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the solution it was due to sqlite finalize statement    .... check all your program you may missed and not placed sqlite finalize statement .. so problem solved :)

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, q, strlen(q), &pointer, 0) == SQLITE_OK){
    //cout<<"\n\n inside loop i values is "<<i<<"\n\n";
    snprintf(fp,MAX_PATH,xbx[i].fpaths,0);
    sqlite3_bind_text(pointer, 1,  fp, strlen(fp), 0); // file name
    sqlite3_step(pointer);   // prepare statemnt Ready 
    sqlite3_reset(pointer);
}
    sqlite3_finalize(pointer);
```

}